# How to find all dependencies between two classes using VS Enterprise Code Map?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, enterprise, code-map

If I pull a class A and class B onto a Code Map, VSE (Visual Studio Enterprise) will map the direct calls of class A calling methods in class B.

So,

```
public class A
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        b.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

This will map. But if it's something like:

```
public class A
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        d.DoManyThings();
    }
}

public class D
{
    public void DoManyThings()
    {
        c.DoThings();
    }
}

public class C
{
    public void DoThings()
    {
        b.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        // imagine code here
    }
}
```

Then the Code Map won't map between class A and class B automatically. The only way I've found to show those dependencies is to go to each method and click "Show Methods This Calls".

Is there a way to get VSE make the Code Map all those dependencies initially without having to investigate every method?